# Adding a space to column values and filtering into ggplot using gsub

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Dear R community members,

I've been cleaning a messy text file that contains over a million observations. 
I've tried multiple times to sort out this problem but it has not worked for me.

Problem: I have a factor column named Travelmode with pre-defined categories as follows:

```
Travelmode 
1
2
3
4
5
```

1 represents Car, 2 represents Inter City Bus, 3 represents Metropolitan Bus, 4 represents Urban rail and 5 represents Community bus and the list goes on on on....... 
I want to replace all occurrences of 1 with Car, all occurrences of 2 with Intercity bus, 3 with Metropolitan Bus, 4 with Urban rail and 5 with Community bus.

To modify the original column values, I have tried to use gsub to no avail.

```
df$Travelmode <- gsub("3", "Metropolitan bus", df$Travelmode)
```

I want to maintain a space between Metropolitan and bus like Metropolitan Bus not Metropolitanbus, Blue bus not Bluebus and so on. These values should appear under my violin and box plots for clarity when i filter as follows:

```
df %>%
  filter(Travelmode %in% c ("Walk","Driver", "Blue bus", "Subway", "Metropolitan bus", "Bicycle", "Urban rail", "Express bus",
                            "Car","Metropolitan bus","Inter city bus" ),
         trippurpose %in% c ("School", "Commute","Shopping","Leisure", "Business"),
         between(df$commutetime2016, 0 , 60)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Travelmode, 
             y = commutetime2016)) +
  geom_violin(fill = "cornflowerblue") +
  geom_boxplot(width = .2, 
               fill = "orange",
               outlier.color = "orange",
               outlier.size = 2) + 
  labs(y = "Travel time (Minutes)", x ="Trip Purpose",title = "Travel time distribution by Mode in 2016")+
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  ylim(0, 90)
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow ... Do you want to edit your data frame to add names instead of the predefined numbers?

Comment: I've edited my problem. Could you please check out again. I want to replace all the occurrences of predefined column values.

Comment: You will need to provide some sample data and code to reproduce the issue you're facing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I keep updating my problem.

Comment: Change Travelmode to a factor with your pre-defined labels.

Comment: Travelmode is already a factor and i have transformed.

Comment: If it's already a factor, then change the levels accordingly. Easy peasy.

Comment: Unfortunately that code isn't working ~ i get this error: Error in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env) : 
 'ORIGINAL_NAME' can not be found

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if I get this correctly, but I think you just want to replace some values with the correct ones (Blue Bus instead of Bluebus)

If so, you could just use `mutate` to do this by combining it with `case_when`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(Travelmode = case_when(
        Travelmode == "Bluebus" ~ "Blue Bus",
        Travelmode == "Metropolitan Bus" ~ "Metropolitan Bus",
        TRUE ~ Travelmode
    )) %>%
...
```

If your original column names are 1,2,3, etc ... then just do

```
df %>% 
    mutate(Travelmode = case_when(
        ORIGINAL_NAME == 1 ~ "Blue Bus",
        ORIGINAL_NAME == 2 ~ "Metropolitan Bus"
    )) %>%
...
```